# Finding Var(X) from a distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, poisson-distribution, variance

I saw this question from an AQA exam:-

The discrete random variable $X$ has probability distribution given by

$P(X = x) = \dfrac {e^{-\lambda}\lambda ^x}{x!}$ for x = 0, 1, 2, … or 0 otherwise.

Find Var(X).

My questions are:-

(1) When I see the probability distribution, I should immediately recognize (assume) that it is a POISSON distribution even the question did not mention that explicitly? (Y/N)

(2) To find Var (X) in general, I should use the standard formula $Var (X) = E(X^2) – (E(X))^2$. But if it is a POISSON distribution, I should use the formula $Var(X) = E(X(X-1))$ instead (meaning the mentioned standard formula should NOT be used at all)? (Y/N)

(3) Can $Var(X) = E(X(X-1))$ be derived from $Var (X) = E(X^2) – (E(X))^2$ for all distributions; or the second is true only when the distribution is POISSON? And if it is derivable please give me a link.

---

***Sorry*** for reading the marking scheme wrongly.
Instead of re-writing my original post, I include the correction in here:-

The question has the first part "Show that $E(X) = \lambda$".

To find Var(x), we need to find $E(X(X - 1)) = ... = \lambda ^2$ first.

Next, from the standard formula, $Var (X) = E(X(X - 1)) + E(X) - (E(X))^2 = E(X(X - 1)) + \lambda - \lambda ^2 = \lambda$.

My further question is then "in finding Var(X), is introducing the x(x-1) factor to the summand in the summation a standard trick?"

Comment: Your formula $var (X) =E(X(X-1))$ is false even for Poisson distribution. It is true if an only if $EX=0$ or $EX=1$.

Comment: $E(X(X-1))\ne var(X)$, the derivation you want is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3026377/260674). The given mass function $P(X=x)$ is the one for the Poisson distribution, knowing the name of the distribution only helps make your statements concise without having to state the density everytime.  And you should always use the formula $Var(X)=E(X^2)-E(X)^2$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Please refer to the "sorry" part.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Please refer to the "sorry" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a *method* to easily compute the variance with the actual value of the variance.  What I mean is that it is easier to directly compute $$\operatorname{E}[X(X-1)] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x(x-1) e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} = \lambda^2 \sum_{x=2}^\infty e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{x-2}}{(x-2)!} = \lambda^2,$$ rather than $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x^2 e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}.$$  In the first calculation, we observe that the summand is zero for $x \in \{0,1\}$, which is why we can ignore the first two terms.  We also note that for $x \ge 2$, $x! = x(x-1)(x-2)!$.  Then pulling out a factor of $\lambda^2$, we obtain the sum of the same Poisson distribution over its support; thus it equals $1$, and the expectation $\operatorname{E}[X(X-1)]$ is $\lambda^2$.  Meanwhile, the second computation is not so simple because we do not have a convenient cancellation of the second factor of $x$, and it is not obvious how to proceed.

The first calculation is in fact a specific case of the more general identity $$\operatorname{E}[X(X-1)\cdots (X-k+1)] = \lambda^k, \quad k \in \{1, 2, \ldots\}.$$

We may then use this calculation to obtain the desired variance; i.e., $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 = \operatorname{E}[X(X-1) + X] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 + \operatorname{E}[X(X-1)] + \operatorname{E}[X] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2,$$ hence $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \lambda^2 + \lambda - \lambda^2 = \lambda.$$

Comment: I got the whole picture (as your description). The corrected version is appended in the "sorry" part.

Answer (score 1):

No need to assume anything, you can use the basic expression $Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$ and solve the question. It happens to be Poisson distribution so you can directly write the variance as $\lambda$ as well.

I have no idea where you got the expression $Var(X) = E[X(X-1)]$. It is simply wrong.
$$E[X(X-1)] = E[X^2]-E[X]$$
$$Var(X) = E[X^2]-E[X]^2 $$
So obviously for a general case, $$ Var(X) \neq E[X(X-1)]$$

Comment: Please refer to the "sorry" part.